# How to check if a WordPress SEO plugin is working

Tags: seo, wordpress, sitemap

I have setup my WordPress site with Yoast.  However, it doesn't seem to appear in any of the search engines.  In Google Webmaster Tools I don't see a sitemap.  Is the plugin supposed to submit the sitemap and should it appear in Google Webmaster Tools?

How do I know if it has been submitted to other search engines?

Comment: Though it's a good idea to have an xml sitemap, Google and other search engines will find your site anyways. I've been running my site for two years now and I never submitted a sitemap.

Comment: @KennethvonRauch the minute/hour/day I submitted my site map google crawled and indexed my pages.  For a month before that it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SEO Yoast plugin will not automatically submit your `sitemap.xml` file on different Search Engines.

Its just created a dynamic `sitemap.xml` for your site.

You can find your sitemap here `http://yourdoamin.com/sitemap_index.xml`.

after set up the Yoast you have do the following things.

1. Allows robots.txt to crawl your site.
2. Dynamically created sitemap should submit to search Engines (Google,bing etc)

when you submit your sitemap to different search engines it will index your file you can check that with their web-master tools.

In Google you can simply find `site:yourdomain.com` in the search, it will return Google indexed pages.

Hope it make sense..

Comment: every time I update the site, won't yoast ping google and other search engines

Comment: every time you update the site its gets update your sitemap.xml file. Search engine will automatically update these changes once you have submitted your sitemap their. is that clear ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the above post, i would recommend signing up for Bing webmaster tools http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster as well

1) Verify your website in both Google and bing webmaster tools. In yoast there is an option for adding the bing and google verification codes;)

2) Add your sitemap.xml to your website settings within bing and google webmaster tools.

3) if you want also want to go the extra mile create a Google+ page, and if you have a location add to Google Maps and Bing places

All simple stuff but a great way to get your site quickly noticed by Google and Bing.

If you wanna go the extra mile again, setup a facebook page and twitter account, as yoast has some great social account features, just create you social profiles and drop the links into yoast;)